# Finding all possible pairwise combinations of a columns in pandas and multiplying their respective cells in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID    Ref     Num_Ref
X     A       2
X     B       3
X     C       1
Y     A       1
Y     C       2
```

I want to find all possible pairs on `Ref`s within each `ID`. And for every pair multiply their number of refs (`Num_Ref`) by each other. So for the above dataframe, the result would look as follows:

```
ID    Ref_pairs   Num_Ref_pairs
X     A_B         6          
X     A_C         2 
X     B_C         3 
Y     A_C         2
```

Note: It doesn't matter how `Ref_pairs` is stored. It can be a string or a tuple... as long as they are in alphabetical order so I can compare them with other similar pairs.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the shape of your original dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

***Recreate your data***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": ["X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y"],
        "Ref": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "C"],
        "Num_Ref": [2, 3, 1, 1, 2,],
    }
)
```

***Iterate through groups and create combinations***

```
import itertools

df_res = []
for id_group, df_group in df.groupby("ID"):
    for comb in itertools.combinations(df_group["Ref"], 2):
        df_res.append(
            {
                "ID": id_group,
                "Ref_pairs": "_".join(comb),
                "Num_Ref_pairs": df_group[df_group.Ref.isin(comb)].product().Num_Ref,
            }
        )
df_res = pd.DataFrame(df_res).set_index("ID")

print(df_res)
ID    Ref_pairs   Num_Ref_pairs
X     A_B         6          
X     A_C         2 
X     B_C         3 
Y     A_C         2
```

Comment: While this works, I wonder if there is a faster way this can be done instead of iterating, as I have about 200 millions unique IDs.

Comment: Are there many different 'Refs'? Or only a few, like in the example?

Comment: There are many different refs. It could be a combinatorics nighmare if you have 1000 refs for example.